# Ajax Calls Returning Zero in IE/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

Have been working on this for 2 days and can't figure out what is causing this to fail in IE (v11) and Firefox. Works fine in Chrome.

Read a lot of questions on here that covered caching issues with multiple Ajax calls, particularly with IE, but I don't believe that's the issue. This code is actually one of two forms on the page. Both are submitted via jQuery, when a "**Submit All**" button is clicked. I disabled the first form, though, and the second still doesn't function properly.

Here's the JS/Ajax code for the faulty form submission:

```
$("body").on( "submit", ".update-guest-email", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    if( form.find('input[name="email"]').val() == "" ) {
        return;
    }
    if (!formChecker(form)){
        return;
    }

    var dataString = {
        action : 'update_guest_party',
        data : form.serializeArray()
    }

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        url: ajaxurl, // This is the WP AJAX handler.
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() {
            form.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function(response){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in response
            if (response.data >= 1){
                form.append('<div class="center confirmed"><span class="dashicons dashicons-yes"></span></div>');
                form.removeClass();
            } else {
                form.find('input').prop('disabled', false);
                $(".errors").html("That's weird; it didn't go through. You can try again or <a href='mailto:email@gmail.com'>send us an email</a>.")
                $('.errors').slideDown(250);
            }
        } // Close success response.
    }); // Close AJAX.
}); // End form-submit.
```

Again, that functions as expected in Chrome. Firebug shows POST data correctly:

```
action          update_guest_party
data[0][name]   email
data[0][value]  brundeezy@gmail.com
data[1][name]   table
data[1][value]  dw_wedding_mgr_guests
data[2][name]   id
data[2][value]  149
```

But then the response is just a '0' (zero). Per Chrome, the response *should* look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":1}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I also have this on a live server, if it would be helpful to see it in production.

Comment: Give us the live server URL and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Mark Sure thing: http://sarahandcasey.com/save-the-date/

Comment: My Chrome 43, Firefox 38 and IE 11 are all returning 'Well fiddlesticks! We couldn't find you.' in the UI. Chrome & Firefox are returning status 200 OK with `{"success":true,"data":{"empty":true}}` in dev tools. IE is returning 200 OK but has no response body. I'll take a closer look in the morning.

Comment: @Mark, oh gah—I knew I was forgetting something. That first call functions properly; search "Michael" and "Brundis", for the first/last name, respectively. Sorry about that, and thanks for your help!

Comment: I've confirmed with Fiddler that all 3 browsers are receiving the exact same response body, and the UI is showing "Groovy, we found you! Please fill out all the fields..."
`fa
{"success":true,"data":{"multiple":false,"parties":[{"id":"84","name":"Brundis","count":"1"}],"guests":[{"id":"149","party_id":"84","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Brundis"},{"id":"263","party_id":"84","first_name":"[REMOVED]","last_name":"[REMOVED]"}]}}
0`
All response headers are identical except Chrome also had 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sarahandcasey.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

Comment: @Mark, If you fill out the address form and at least one email address line (it can be junk info), what do you get? For me, in IE and Firefox, the email forms are what's causing confusion. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: In `success: function(response)`, response == "0" and response.data == undefined, therefore `if (response.data >= 1)` is always false. Looks like a server problem and possibly client too depending on what you expected in `response.data`. This is on all 3 browsers. Response is gzipped but browsers seem to be decoding this fine.

Comment: @Mark, that's odd. I actually had removed the Address form class during debugging last night, and just re-added it. So if you go back and resubmit, you *should* get a success checkmark on the address. But it's odd that your email didn't work in Chrome? Because that's worked all along, and still works for me.

On the address, I get a response of:
{"success":true,"data":{"rows":2}}

On the emails, I get a response of:
{"success":true,"data":1}

Same exact thing in IE/Firefox, except that Firebug shows my response for the email ajax call as a simple '0'. Very strange, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now getting around to posting my "solution" here and, as usual, it's a piece of cake.

The issue had nothing to do with browsers. As we started to figured out above, everything was server-side. WordPress requires a ["nopriv" version of its "wp_ajax_" hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) to function on the front-end of a website. In other words, the reason it wasn't working in other browsers, was because I hadn't signed in as an admin with anything other than Chrome. This also explains why Mark saw the same issue in Chrome, because he (obviously) hadn't signed in, either.

Below is the code I ended up using, in case you'd like to see an example. Same function ("bulk_update_address"), just need to duplicate it with the aforementioned "nopriv" version of the hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_bulk_update_address', 'bulk_update_address' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_bulk_update_address', 'bulk_update_address' );
```

I actually had a "nopriv" line there ahead of time...just forgot to remove the commenting around it. Ay-ay-ay. Hope this saves somebody a headache in the future!